# hibernate relationship left join

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have got 3 entities:

```
class A {
   @ManyToOne
   B b1;

   @ManyToOne
   B b2;
   ...
}

class B {
...
}

class C {
   @ManyToOne
   B b;
}
```

I would like to left join the "A" class "b2" field with "C" class "b" field in HQL.
So the hql what i woild like:

```
SELECT a FROM A as a INNER JOIN a.b1 LEFT JOIN C as c on a.b2=c.b
```

But I can not use left join in this case, because class A and class C are not connected.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Given that the HQL is invalid, I don't see what it's supposed to do. Could you explain, for example with example data, what the query should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik, there is no way to perform outer join in HQL if entities has no relationship. (from my knowledge until Hibernate 3.x. :P )

Consider writing SQL in such case

Comment: I put a manytomany connection to the entities, with lazy loading, and after that, i can use it in hql.